# How to toggle Show/Hide hidden files in Windows through command line?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, system-file

I often need to toggle between show/hide hidden files in my PC. I have been doing it the usual way,

- Click Organize in an Explorer window.
- Select Folder and search options.
- Switch to View tab.
- Toggle between Show/Hide Hidden files.

This method is so lengthy and I am tired of it.

I would like to toggle between them from the command line (cmd). Is there any way to achieve  this?

Also, a way to toggle between Show/Hide System Files from the command line would be great.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Hidden files, folders or drives:**

Add (or overwrite `/f`) the value `Hidden` to the registry key: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`.

Show:

`reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

Don't show:

`reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f`

ToggleHiddenFiles.bat

```
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v Hidden | Find "0x2"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto turnoff
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto turnon

goto end
:turnon
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
goto end

:turnoff
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
goto end

:end
```

**Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)**

Checked:

`reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v ShowSuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

Unchecked:

`reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v ShowSuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

ToggleSystemFiles.bat

```
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v ShowSuperHidden | Find "0x0"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto turnoff
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto turnon

goto end
:turnon
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v ShowSuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
goto end

:turnoff
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v ShowSuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
goto end

:end
```

**Notes:** Changes take place immediately.  The program `reg` requires admin privileges, so run the batch files as administrator.

Comment: Don't you need to kill and restart the explorer.exe process for registry changes to actually get applied?

Comment: @Zoredache The settings take effect immediately either from the Folder Options and the registry change.  Try it and see.

Comment: @RogUE No, because the script is testing the result of the `find` command (whether `0x2` or `0x0` is present in the registry key).

Comment: @RogUE In the first script, the `REQ QUERY` command will be returning a string containing either `0x1` or `0x2` and the `find` command is looking for the presence (or not) of `0x2`.  If this string _is_ found, `find` returns `ERRORLEVEL` of `0` (zero is traditionally "it worked" in command-line programs); if `0x2` wasn't found, `find` will return `1`.  It is the return-code of the `find` command that is being tested in the next two lines.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a typo: it's checking for the presence of `0x0`; if it's found (`find` returns `0`) then it jumps to `turnon` and sets the value to `1`; if it's not found (`find` returns `1`) then it jumps to `turnoff` and sets it to `0`.  _Either_ it's an arbitrary choice (and the test could have been `find 0x1` with the `goto`s reversed) _or_ it might be (I haven't checked) that `0x1` is present in the `REQ QUERY` output in either case and so cannot be used to tell the two settings apart.

Comment: @Steven The toggle scripts did the job. Though I could not assign them to a keyboard shortcut, I ended up placing an icon on the desktop.

Answer (score 3):

The property to show/hide hidden files is managed in the registry, so you would simply need a .reg file that simply toggles this property. Here is how you do it through registry:

- Type “regedit“, then press “Enter“.
- Navigate to the following location: HKEY_CURRENT_USER --> Software --> Microsoft --> Windows --> CurrentVersion --> Explorer --> Advanced
- Set the value for “Hidden” to “1” to show hidden files, folders, and drives.
- Set the value to “2” to not show hidden files, folders, and drives.
- Set the value for “ShowSuperHidden” to “1” to show protected operating system files. Set the value to “2” to not show protected operating system files.

<strike>If you give me a bit of time, I will write the REG file and post it here.</strike>
Edit: Steven seems to have posted an example script, so I won't build one.

Comment: @RogUE : Yes, the ShowSuperHidden is for the system files that are hidden.

Comment: @RogUE I am unsure what the SuperHidden value does.  However, it does always reset to zero whenever the View tab of the Folder Options applet is opened the first time.

Comment: Check the setting.  Close Folder Options.  Run my toggle script.  Repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I know you arent using it but its worth considering the upgrade.
The process in Windows 10 is:
Alt + V
H
H

You need more keystrokes to open the command prompt in Windows 7.

Comment: I am not going to upgrade just for the sake of a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a command line function, here's a method on how to quickly open the window: Show hidden files and folders.

Caution: Review source information in Part 1 concerning Vista before proceeding.

**Part 1:** Create a folder that contains the object 'Show hidden files and folders'.

**Part 2:** Create a desktop shortcut of 'Show hidden files and folders'.

**Part 3:** Open the window for 'Show hidden files and folder'

After you have completed all 3 parts you will have a keyboard shortcut for quick access to the window for 'Show hidden files and folders'.

**Part 1**

1. Right click a blank area of the desktop
2. Click New
3. Click Folder
4. Name the folder: How-To Geek.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8711/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-the-secret-how-to-geek-mode-in-windows/

**Part 2:**

5. Open the How-To Geek folder you just created
6. Click the arrow next to File Explorer Options if it's not already expanded
7. Right click and drag to the desktop 'Show hidden files and folders'
8. Click create shortcut here

Note: In this particular situation you could left click and drag, but it's always good practice to right click and drag to ensure you are performing the intended function, and because you can also click cancel if needed.

**Part 3:**

9. Right click the shortcut folder on the desktop 'Show hidden files and folders'
10. Click Properties
11. On the Shortcut tab click in the Shortcut Key field
12. Press something like Ctrl + Alt + T
13. Click OK
14. Press Ctrl + Alt + T and the 'Show hidden files and folders' will open

Answer (score 0):

A possibly more convenient way to accomplish this with minimal effort is through adding a context menu item, to do this:

1. Create a new simple text document somewhere and name it "togglehidden.reg"
2. Open it with notepad and paste the following:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Windows.ShowHiddenFiles]
   "CommandStateSync"=""
   "Description"="@shell32.dll,-37573"
   "ExplorerCommandHandler"="{f7300245-1f4b-41ba-8948-6fd392064494}"
   "MUIVerb"="@shell32.dll,-37572"


   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Windows.ShowHiddenFiles]
   "CommandStateSync"=""
   "Description"="@shell32.dll,-37573"
   "ExplorerCommandHandler"="{f7300245-1f4b-41ba-8948-6fd392064494}"
   "MUIVerb"="@shell32.dll,-37572"
   ```
3. save and close.
4. double click your new reg file, accept prompts to install it and you're done.

This is what you should get:
[Hidden Toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1rsg.png)

Source: https://winaero.com/blog/hidden-items-context-menu-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steven's reply, I could wrote software that toggles this (and refresh open explorer windows) with a single click: [Link](https://csharpsoftwareza.blogspot.com/2019/01/toggle-hidden-filesfolders.html)

Edit:

When the application is opened, it gets a value from the registry key (Hidden) here: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced.

Depending on the value, a hidden command prompt to change the value is executed. Thereafter every open windows explorer window is refreshed and hidden files/folders is hidden/shown.

It is available for vieweing in the [source](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=kZDsHK7Z51Nq0ITfYO5DYK0R2KPB557E1GNV).

Answer (score 0):

My OS is Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit.
I was interested in a command line to show/hide protected files.
Using the reg keys in batch files, it worked well from hidden to show, but not reversely.
Digging the registry, I noticed that a key was not immediately updated, requesting a restart of the computer.
Its location is `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-445602408-3241513752-1080421046-1001\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`.
But as Explorer parameters are involved, I had the idea to close and restart it.
It works now perfectly.

Here are my two batch files:
Hide:

```
@echo off
Reg add Hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v ShowSuperHidden /t Reg_Dword /d 0 /f > nul
Taskkill /Im Explorer.exe > nul & Explorer =
Cls & exit
```

Show:

```
@echo off
Reg add Hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v ShowSuperHidden /t Reg_Dword /d 1 /f > nul
Taskkill /Im Explorer.exe > nul & Explorer =
Cls & exit
```

They will open "My PC" when applied.
As previously said, they must be run as administrator, either in DOS mode in the System32 folder, or elsewhere from a right click on their names.
Hope this will help if some of yours encounter issues similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

To enable "Show hidden files" in Windows explorer, run the following in powershell:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name "Hidden" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

Then, to make this change take effect, either reboot/log out and back in or optionally, restart explorer by running:

```
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
explorer.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined them into a single batch script and while the registry value does update, the values displayed in File Explorer Options -->View did not change, even if running as administrator.

Testing revealed that an Explorer restart is truly needed, at least under W10 Pro x64, which makes no sense given that REG values are supposubly ;) updated immediately. But I did not need to run the batch file as administrator.

Here's my working code...

```
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v Hidden | Find "0x2"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto turnoff
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto turnon

goto end
::show hidden and system files
:turnon
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v ShowSuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
goto end

::hide hidden and system files
:turnoff
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v ShowSuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
goto end

:end
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1088742)