# Can I unhide a single folder or file with batch script?

Tags: windows, batch, properties

I want to make a script that can unhide a *single* given file or folder. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1151844/how-to-toggle-show-hide-hidden-files-in-windows-through-command-line) question covers how to switch between hiding or unhiding all files, but I want to know how to do the same for only one given item. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To hide a file or folder, use the following command:**

```
attrib +h <target file/folder>
```

**To unhide a file or folder, do the opposite:**

```
attrib -h <target file/folder>
```

**To hide all files/folders inside a given folder, first** `cd` **into this folder in question and then use this command:**

```
attrib +h /s /d
```

**And of course to unhide all the files and folders inside a directory,** `cd` **into it and issue the opposite of the previous command:**

```
attrib -h /s /d
```